# At what point does a file reflect its true size after being written to?

Tags: linux, shell, files, linux-kernel

I have a process that is (supposedly) writing to a file on regular intervals using libparquet/libarrow's StreamWriter (Should write out every ~65MB). When querying the file via the shell e.g. `watch du -sh {file_name}`, it does not appear to grow in size. However, when the process finishes, it appears that the file has been fully written to.

What exactly is going on behind the scenes here? I'm guessing the process has opened the file and is continuing to write to it until done, but when is the file's actual size reflected to the user (or OS)? Is it once the file is finally closed?

When I write to a file in python repeatedly e.g. `with open('file.txt','w') as fp`, querying the file in the shell via `ls` or `du` reflects the file's actual size. Is this python just adding in extra steps behind the scenes?

Comment: ~65MB is a bit large for block buffering. what does `strace` or such show the process doing for I/O calls?

Comment: I mostly see `brk` calls which I'm assuming are increasing memory allocations and `munmap` and `mmap` which i'm not really sure what it's for unless it's something that libparquet uses

Comment: Does `watch "sync;du -sh {file_name}"` work?

Comment: If you want to see the size, use `ls -l`. `du` reports the disk usage, not size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without details on what method the program uses, the answer is
"somewhere between very quickly and never" as there are many ways to do
I/O and many things that can go wrong along the way. Also various
operating systems or filesystems may complicate matters, and are not
covered here.

Note that some systems may require that random magic strings be defined
to compile the test programs shown below; see e.g.
`feature_test_macros(7)` on some flavors of Linux. You'll probably also
need a C99 compiler, which lots of folks (but not everyone...) provide
these days.

### write

`write(2)` is pretty simple; the output from this call should appear
towards the quicker end of the spectrum (if all goes well) due to the
lack of buffering and here the lack of anything else going on in the
code. It may be educational to run these scripts under `ktrace` or
`strace` or some other such system call tracing utility.

```
// write.c -- `rm out; make write && ./write > out`
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(void) {
    char buf[] = "this is some output\n";
    //while(1) {
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf, sizeof(buf) / sizeof(char));
    //}
    return 0;
}
```

Uncomment the infinite loop for more output and add `sleep(3)` calls to
slow things down to aid with the "what does the filesystem show?" tests.

### Buffering... Buffering... Buffering...

Real Programs(TM) may use buffered I/O and may have too many other
things going on (bloat); we'll only cover the buffering here. First up,
a program that emits output never:

```
// never.c -- `rm out; make never && ./never > out`
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(void) {
    setvbuf(stdout, 0, _IOFBF, 0);
    fputs("x", stdout);
    _exit(0);
}
```

This selects full buffering but then exits without flushing anything.
There are many other ways to make this happen, such as folks getting
frisky with `kill -9`, segfaults, etc. Usually quick output could turn
into "almost never" if the system is simply very, very, very busy, such
as when a dual processor linux system had a CPU load of 5,000 or so...

Simple modifications here would be to change `_exit` to `exit` then add
a `sleep` call prior to that to simulate delayed output to the
filesystem, then to add an infinite loop with sleeps to delay output to
fill up whatever the buffer size is, etc. Anyways, with buffering the
output size on the filesystem will probably lag behind what the program
has written by some amount.

### Rename a Temporary File

Another trick is to write to a temporary file, then to rename the
temporary to the actual file when the I/O completes; this avoids the
problem of a reader seeing a half-written output file. In this case the
output file will reflect the new size only after the `rename(2)` call.

```
// rename.c -- `rm out*; make rename && ./rename & sleep 1; ls -l out*`
#include <err.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(void) {
    char *tmpbuf  = strdup("out.XXXXXXXXXX");
    char *tmpfile = mktemp(tmpbuf);
    if (!tmpfile) err(1, "mktemp failed");
    FILE *fh = fopen(tmpfile, "w");
    if (!fh) err(1, "fopen failed");
    fputs("this is some renamed output\n", fh);
    fclose(fh);
    sleep(9);
    rename(tmpfile, "out");
    //free(tmpbuf);
    return 0;
}
```

Here, the `out` file should only reflect the new size after nine seconds
or so. Or, many many more seconds when the system is very very busy. Or,
never, should something fail before the rename completes.

### Memory Mapping

Yet another way to do I/O is via memory mapping. This however does
not show any signs of buffering, though there may be flags to change
this behavior.

```
// mmap.c -- `make mmap && ./mmap & sleep 1; od -bc out`
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <err.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(void) {
    char buf[]    = "this is some mmap'd output\n";
    size_t buflen = sizeof(buf) / sizeof(char);
    int fd        = open("out", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0666);
    ftruncate(fd, buflen);
    if (fd < 0) err(1, "open failed");
    void *ptr = mmap(0, buflen, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    if (ptr == MAP_FAILED) err(1, "mmap failed");
    sleep(9);
    memcpy(ptr, buf, buflen);
    munmap(ptr, buflen);
    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

A memory mapped file could be renamed from a temporary file to the
expected file once I/O is complete (see the previous trick). There may
be good reasons for doing so.

### Other

There may be other forms of I/O available that use different system
calls than those presented above. `strace` or such should reveal them,
if you know what to look for. They may have buffering that may delay the
apperance of the output on the filesystem. Writing simple scripts will
help to show how the calls behave and this should help show what to look
for in a larger program under `strace`. Hopefully there is
documentation.

### Piled Higher and Deeper

Languages built on top of the standard library may have their own
buffering in addition to (or besides) what the operating system
provides, though will usually have a `flush` or `(finish-output)` or
some such call to try to get the bits off to disk, and perhaps a `sync`
call of some sort to adjust the default behavior like `setvbuf(3)` lets
you do. Or not. Some languages or programming guides may set different
defaults than the operating system. Buffered output may show delays
getting to the filesystem, or the rename trick may be in use.

Comment: Also be aware that there can be buffering at the controller, at the RAID and at the disk as appropriate.  Network filesystems will also exhibit buffering during transfer and then down the stack on the remote machine.

Comment: But physical buffering is below the filesystem, so won't affect the output of `du`, etc @Martin

Comment: Hence not an answer, merely a comment to be aware.  Hopefully systems have adequate battery backup to the RAIDs ... !